# JWPlayer skin configuration after setup

Tags: jquery, facebook, jwplayer

i am trying to apply a skin to JWPlayer after the function setup() including a different skin is completed. I am trying to replace the skin param with my own skin through jquery.

The first time i see it but if the page loads inside a facebook iframe the skin gets lost and i see the default skin.

Is there a way to apply a skin after the setup of JWPlayer has been completed?

Comment: If you are running this in an iframe on the Facebook website then I don't think you can load the skin cross-domain because it's pulled-in client-side where cross-domain-policies apply.

Comment: i Get to load it only once the first time when i load the tab in facebook with a setInterval(); function but then if i click the tab again it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately not............

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/addons/using-and-creating-skins/31469/apply-skins-after-setup